# Vertical DIV liquid layout issue

Tags: html, css, vertical-scrolling, liquid-layout

Given the following HTML/CSS, what is the simplest way of implementing a vertical 'liquid' DIV (#ribbon1 and #ribbon2) that grows with the content of the #content DIV?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #container {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -400px;
                top: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 800px;
            }

            #ribbon1 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 702px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 46px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #ribbon2 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 752px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 30px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: blue;
            }

            #content {
                left:16px;
                width:687px;
            }
            -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="ribbon1"></div>
            <div id="ribbon2"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum ea pro lorem tantas platonem, duo ut abhorreant percipitur. Quo elit aperiri disputationi at, cum ex choro vivendo delicatissimi, ne magna conceptam adolescens has. Admodum persecuti reprimique nec ei. Te possim labitur perpetua vix, ad eos audire vituperatoribus. No dicat repudiandae est, nec an assum oporteat concludaturque. Ei pro accumsan consequat dissentiet, pri malis affert at.</p>
                <p>Sed ut diam iudico, vis mutat decore ea. Tota illum officiis ei eum, per mucius consequuntur ex, quo tota vocibus ad. Et liber similique vituperata mel, an inani utamur principes qui. Nostro definitionem ius ad. Usu viris tritani et, ea pri noster takimata delicatissimi. Sea dictas recteque convenire ex, malorum percipit qui ut, an quod placerat ius. Ex sed antiopam principes, te posse alienum est, sea delenit debitis conceptam at.</p>
                <p>Ad clita audire conceptam nec. Eos ei corpora tincidunt dissentiunt, qui ne vocent eripuit habemus. Eum ut oportere incorrupte reformidans, eu ius dicit tibique intellegebat. Ut has noluisse insolens, saepe integre eu mel. Ut vel prima periculis constituam, id nisl principes cotidieque sed, ad per nullam virtute instructior. Et has error oblique nominavi, ut pro magna summo labitur.</p>
                <p>Malorum facilisis ei nec, erant molestiae vim ut. Velit dolor invidunt ut cum. Etiam timeam docendi vix ad, in alii latine hendrerit qui. Ad has idque option, probatus tractatos ut qui, sit altera latine suscipiantur ex. In omnium platonem vel, sea no sumo denique. Ei mei vidisse invidunt interpretaris.</p>
                <p>Quo corrumpit gubergren at, ne mel omnes adipisci ullamcorper, scripserit efficiantur mei eu. In reque mazim mea. Mea ex sonet inermis volutpat. Habemus erroribus in sed, no est mutat clita. Harum urbanitas scriptorem qui at, pri cu expetenda referrentur. Has alia ullum tractatos te, his justo laoreet consetetur ex.</p>
                <p>Et oratio consul pro, ei pri equidem tibique ullamcorper. Mucius eligendi assentior cu sea. His ut tota postulant accommodare, putant eligendi scaevola id cum, option vocibus scribentur est in. Pro splendide appellantur ut, an elit omnis audire vix. Habeo tincidunt usu id, sed diam splendide vituperatoribus te.</p>
                <p>Tractatos mediocrem ea usu, id deleniti recusabo cotidieque cum. Cu mea eruditi salutandi. Eu usu dolore partem salutatus, detracto fabellas mel no. Ex ius falli prompta invidunt, et est possim constituam dissentiunt.</p>
                <p>Legendos prodesset ad sed, labore viderer periculis ad eam, stet sadipscing id pri. Ex sea quis quidam, no natum adipiscing efficiendi eum. Noluisse antiopam repudiare ex vel, tation principes eam ea. Eam illud oratio tempor ei, feugiat dolorum accusamus mel ei. Cu cum suas nibh.</p>
                <p>Natum primis apeirian nec an, te duo eros tation lucilius. Iusto dicam necessitatibus est at, at nominati atomorum his. Aliquid verterem laboramus ei has, suas augue postea et pro. Velit euripidis ne est, an inermis minimum qui. Cum dico animal neglegentur no.</p>
                <p>Pro probo veritus cu. Ex quis pertinax cum. Sumo senserit in ius. Dicam melius in cum. Nobis partem te usu, ut suas ornatus nec, ut tantas mucius possit ius. Unum definitiones pri ne, suas legimus volutpat sit ea. Eos dicat senserit electram id, te usu congue delicata reformidans, pro ut cibo minim.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have read that absolute positioned child DIVs don't allow their parent DIV to grow with them, and I'd like to avoid writing some JS that dynamically resizes them. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the ribbons are just for aesthetics and not intended to hold content, go with imjared's solution. If you plan to put content in them and that content will never push the bottom of the ribbons below the main content, ramblex's solution is good (as long as you don't care about IE6... and we should *all* stop caring about IE6!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing #container to the following seemed to work for me in Chrome, Safari, opera and FF (untested on IE).

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Good job! This seems to work in IE7 too and is the simplest answer. The only issue I have now in Chrome and FF is the 'ribbon' DIVs have padding from the top, but that's a separate issue/question.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second div and modify the absolutely positioned ribbons to be border-rights. I'm not always a big fan of non-semantic divs but in some cases, it's just the easiest solution.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100%; }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -400px;
            top: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 800px;
        }

        #content {
            left:16px;
            width:687px;
            border-right: 15px solid red;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        #content2 { border-right: 15px solid blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!--<div id="ribbon1"></div>-->
        <!--<div id="ribbon2"></div>-->
        <div id="content">
            <div id="content2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum ea pro lorem tantas platonem, duo ut abhorreant percipitur. Quo elit aperiri disputationi at, cum ex choro vivendo delicatissimi, ne magna conceptam adolescens has. Admodum persecuti reprimique nec ei. Te possim labitur perpetua vix, ad eos audire vituperatoribus. No dicat repudiandae est, nec an assum oporteat concludaturque. Ei pro accumsan consequat dissentiet, pri malis affert at.</p>
            </div><!--/#content2-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Just be sure to modify the padding appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
.ribbon1{position:absolute;left0;top:0;bottom:0;right:50%;}
.ribbon2{position:absolute;left:50%;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;}
```